# Кроссдоменные запросы

Tags: javascript, https, cross-domain, cross-origin

С моей html страницы открываю другую ссылку (в отдельной вкладке) и хочу обновлять её каждые 5 секунд. Но запрос происходит на другой домен:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost"
>   from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.google.by". The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Открываю новую вкладку так:

```
  var win = window.open("https://www.google.com", "tab");
  setInterval(function () { win.location.reload() }, 5000);
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с этой проблемой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Нельзя читать свойство location, но зато можно записывать данные, поэтому reload заменил на `win.location.href = url;`
Источник - [Исключение: запись в location](http://learn.javascript.ru/same-origin-policy#%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-location)